# Recursive CTE with a Where clause not returning all results

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a UserTypes table like this:

```
UserTypeID | ParentUserTypeID | Name
1            NULL               Person
2            NULL               Company
3            2                  IT
4            3                  Accounting Software
```

What I want to do is get all the `ParentUserTypeID` when a UserTypeID is passed to the CTE. I have got this so far but it only returns one `ParentUserTypeID` rather than all of them in the tree.

```
   ;WITH CTE 
    AS
    (
    SELECT 
        c1.ParentUserTypeID,
        c1.UserTypeID,
        c1.Name
    FROM 
        dbo.UserTypes c1
    WHERE 
        ParentUserTypeID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        c2.ParentUserTypeID,
        c2.UserTypeID,
        c2.Name 
    FROM 
        dbo.UserTypes c2
        INNER JOIN CTE
        ON c2.ParentUserTypeID = CTE.UserTypeID
    )
    SELECT 
        ParentUserTypeID,
        UserTypeID
    FROM 
        CTE
    WHERE
        UserTypeID = 4
```

I get a result of:

```
UserTypeID  | ParentUserTypeID  
4             3
```

### **EDIT/UPDATE**

What I actually need is a list of all the `UserTypeID`s in the hierarchy tree associated with the specified `@UserTypeID`. A bit like this:

```
UserTypeID | ParentUserTypeID
2            NULL
3            2
4            3
```

I can then use my application to loop around this and insert a UserID along with the UserTypeIDs applicable something like this:

```
<cfloop query="rsUserTypeIDs"> // loops around the UserTypeIDs brought back from the CTE
INSERT INTO dbo.User_UserType (UserID, UserTypeID)
VALUES
(
#UserID#                    // Provided by the web application
#rsUserTypeIDs.UserTypeID#  // Each time it loops it gets the UserTypeID from the CTE
)  
</cfloop>
```

The above code is not relevant to this question. I put it there so you understand what I'm doing with the results of the CTE.

How can I correct the recursive CTE so that it returns the `UserTypeID`s all the way up to the top of the tree instead of just the one row showing its immediate `ParentUserTypeID`?

Comment: change this bit:
 SELECT 
        c2.ParentUserTypeID,
        c2.UserTypeID,
        c2.Name 
    FROM 
        dbo.Company c2
        INNER JOIN CTE
        ON c2.ParentUserTypeID = CTE.UserTypeID
and add
OR c2.ParentUserTypeId IS NULL

Comment: I'm looking at your code and would like to help, but I don't see where [UserID] is defined so I'm having trouble understanding what the requirement is. Also, your desired results is for a return set of [UserTypeID] in (4,3,2), but for [UserTypeID] of 2, the [ParentUserTypeID] is null. This is confusing. Could you please clarify your requirements so I can try to address the issue?

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey You can find the table structure in an earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715161/check-if-a-value-exists-in-the-child-parent-tree

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey sorry, I included that as like a "final destination" of WHY i'm doing this. It doesn't have anything to do with the problem situation as such. Its a carry on from a previous question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715161/check-if-a-value-exists-in-the-child-parent-tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how much you are allowed / desiring to change the structure, but you probably need to define the UserTypeID you are looking up in the CTE root, e.g.:

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
SELECT 
    c1.ParentUserTypeID,
    c1.UserTypeID,
    c1.Name
FROM 
    dbo.UserTypes c1
WHERE 
    UserTypeID = 4

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    c2.ParentUserTypeID,
    c2.UserTypeID,
    c2.Name 
FROM 
    dbo.UserTypes c2
    INNER JOIN CTE
    ON c2.UserTypeID = CTE.ParentUserTypeID
)
SELECT 
    ParentUserTypeID,
    UserTypeID
FROM 
    CTE
```

[SQL Fiddle results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01262/6)

Comment: Its still only returning 1 row. Its not returning all the rows?

Comment: Updated the SQL Fiddle with the right query - sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/206af/6)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTypes
(
  UserTypeId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ParentUserTypeId INT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(50)
 )


INSERT INTO UserTypes
VALUES
    (1,NULL, 'Person'),
    (2, NULL, 'Company'),
    (3,2, 'IT'),
    (4,3,'Accounting Software')
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
        c1.ParentUserTypeID,
        c1.UserTypeID,
        c1.Name, 
        1 as Level
    FROM 
        UserTypes c1
    WHERE 
        UserTypeId =4

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
        c2.ParentUserTypeID,
        c2.UserTypeId,
        c2.Name,
        CTE.Level + 1 As Level
  FROM UserTypes c2
  INNER JOIN CTE 
    ON CTE.ParentUserTypeID = C2.UserTypeId
)
SELECT UserTypeId, ParentUserTypeID
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Level Desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/206af/6/0)**:

```
| USERTYPEID | PARENTUSERTYPEID |
|------------|------------------|
|          2 |           (null) |
|          3 |                2 |
|          4 |                3 |
```

Comment: thanks this look interesting. I just updated my question to give a better idea of the result I need. Can you suggest how I can get the kind of output I need?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to:

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
SELECT 
    c1.ParentUserTypeID,
    c1.UserTypeID,
    c1.Name
FROM 
    dbo.Company c1
WHERE 
    ParentUserTypeID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CTE.ParentUserTypeID,
    c2.UserTypeID,
    c2.Name 
FROM 
    dbo.Company c2
    INNER JOIN CTE
    ON c2.ParentUserTypeID = CTE.UserTypeID
)
SELECT 
    ParentUserTypeID,
    UserTypeID,
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE
    UserTypeID = 4
```

Use CTE.ParentUserTypeID instead of c2.ParentUserTypeID in the union clause. Otherwise you add the same line in the recursion.

Comment: I just updated my question to give a better idea of the result I need. Can you suggest how I can get the kind of output I need?